# After setting up the example Loopback app, how come my StrongOps dashboard stays empty?

Tags: node.js, strongloop, loopbackjs

I followed the guidelines for installing *Loopback* example app, and registering to *StrongOps* monitoring service, like documented in the [Getting Started](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Getting+started) doc

**Installing and registering was flawless, but now I don't see nothing happening on my StrongOps dashboard, why ?**

I even followed the step of running the stress test to be sure that some metrics are sent, but the dashboard stays empty.

```
$ slc run bin/create-load.js
```

**Side note :** The documentation does not mention the fact that when you quit the `REPL` command line, you actually stops the web server. First time I did this, I could not load the stress tests and did not understand why, until I realize the app was offline. Trivial, but should be in a *Getting started* doc.

Version used :

```
$ slc version                                                       
slc v2.2.2 (node v0.10.22)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, you got caught between rolling out updates to our tooling on npmjs.org, and updates to our documentation. We recommend running with strong-supervisor, which should be co-installed with strong-cli, though you may have to update:

```
npm install -g strong-supervisor
npm update -g strong-cli
```

At this point, you can run with

```
sl-run
```

and it will run the sample (or any app, without having to add a direct dependency on strong-agent) with strong-agent profiling, and strong-cluster-control worker/robustness management.

https://github.com/strongloop/strong-supervisor

We'll be continuing to work on our tooling integration over the next few sprints.

Answer (score 3):

I believe there was a weekend maintenance done on StrongOps today. Can you retry ?

I am getting my data right now.

Shubhra

Comment: That would explain. It seems better now indeed. However, a live app does not stop during week ends :) I am only testing for now, but do you know if there is some kind of StrongLoop infrastructure monitoring dashboard for clients ? With planned downtimes schedules and such ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out.

Despite the documentation says the example app comes out of the box with *strongOps* support, it does not.

I had to enable it manually :

```
$ npm install strong-agent
```

In `app.js`, before the app dependencies :

```
require('strong-agent').profile();
```

Then, I relaunched the example app and now the dashboards starts to looks like there is something

However the charts stay empty for the moment, despite the example app and load app have been running for about 1/2 hour.

[image: Screenshot]